# Why I can't change "On startup" Chrome option?

Tags: google-chrome

When I go to `chrome://settings/` the options under `On startup` are disabled, like read-only options. How can I change these options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove whatever is under this Windows Registry Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`.

**Note:** You can run Registry Editor typing  `regedit.exe` in Windows Start box (Search programs and files)

Comment: The real question is, how did those policies/policy templates get installed in the first place?

Comment: The guy who install my PC and all the software put set up such gesitry values.

Comment: I found them under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`

Comment: My solution was similar to gsi-frank's, however I found that my system had a slightly more advanced set of policies set.  I had to go under `HKEY_USERS\weirdkeyname\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome` to locate the offending registry keys.  Note that `weirdkeyname` wasn't the actual name, but it was a lengthy, seemingly random string; there were several such ones that appeared to have been setup by the admins at my company.

Comment: `HEY_CURRENT_USER` might have same key(s) too, you all should check there.

Comment: This seems a bit dangerous for some cases. In my case I would delete some other company policies which I am not sure what would happen. So I followed [Sinai R.'s](https://superuser.com/a/1341188/389874) answer and added a new value which worked just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use regedit.exe and go to the `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` key.

Inside, change `RestoreOnStartup` to a `1`.

Answer (score 1):

1. From PowerShell:

```ps
notepad $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
```

2. If notepad prompts you to create a new file, choose Yes.
3. Add the following to the file and save it. Adjust [the values](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#RestoreOnStartupGroup) as necessary to match your desired preferences.

```ps
function Fix-Chrome {
    try {
        # This may be superfluous
        del HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\Recommended\ -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {}
    Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome HomepageIsNewTabPage 1
    Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome ShowHomeButton 0
    Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome RestoreOnStartup 1 # Restore the last session
}
```

4. Whenever needed, run the following command at an elevated PS prompt and then relaunch Chrome:

```ps
Fix-Chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Download the **attached zip folder and extract the files.
- Open ***runPerkSearchChecker***.
- Run the Reset Your Browser program.

** [ResetMyBrowser.zip](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/group/chrome/attach/eb714ba11b98f2d/ResetMyBrowser.zip?part=2)

Reference: [Google foruns](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/KpQ0OTBdZFo/dedowU4aP2UJ)

Comment: I try uninstalling and re installing Chrome and not work, so this method will not work neither. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @gsc-frank, Try this method mentioned by me.

Comment: I read the reference link you put in your answer and even my problem is similar, my startup page is not Perk. I already know what is my problem, will post the solution tomorrow when return to the office. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your Chrome Enterprise administrator set and locked these settings for efficiency or security reasons. You can check your administrator's policies at chrome://policy/

Comment: Welcome.  You could improve your answer by providing a  bit more information such as which fields to check or even screenshots.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).