# How can I stop HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome being set?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Some idiot in our IT department has changed the registry setting under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
```

to make it always open at the company homepage rather than "Continue where you left off" which is what I prefer. I can turn this off (see [Why I can't change "On startup" Chrome option?](https://superuser.com/questions/590726/why-i-cant-change-on-startup-chrome-option)) but is there any way I can stop them changing it again?

Comment: How is that "idiot" applying this every time? Group Policy?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. They're not changing it manually on my PC so I assume it's being done via Group Policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the permissions on the registry keys to deny.

Open up the Registry Editor, navigate to the key HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome, and then right click and select 'Permissions'.

Uncheck 'Full Control' on SYSTEM and any other accounts than your own (like 'Domain Admins' or something like that).

Edit:

If you cannot uncheck it (it's grayed out), try checking 'Full Control' on the *Deny* column.

Comment: I don't seem to have permission to do that.

Comment: @parsley72 Are you getting a permission denied or is SYSTEM's area grayed out?

Comment: It's greyed out.

Comment: @parsley72 See my edit. Can you check 'Full Control' on the deny column?

Comment: Yes, that seems to have worked. I'll see what happens next time I reboot.

Comment: I dont see this registry key and am trying to set curtain mode.

Comment: the Full Control is disabled, is there any method to change it?